# 2 physical interfaces change the link to a different interface name, on reboot

Tags: linux-networking, ethernet, interface, ubuntu-18.04, adapter

### Environment:

I have two physical network interfaces on my system:

1. Qualcomm Atheros Ethernet
2. Realtek Ethernet (RTL-8169)

On the system, i have `Ubuntu-18.04`.

### Problem:

I have configured:

- `Realtek` to be used as a `management-network` - (with **eth0**, e.g a.b.c.20/24)
- `Qualcomm Atheros` to be used as a `provider-network` - (with **eth1**, e.g a.b.c.120/24)

When i reboot, sometimes `Realtek` adapter gets eth0/eth1. I don't want this behaviour.

Is there a way to bound each physical-interface to a specific interface name, statically.

### Note

I don't want to configure network-interfaces from the directory `/etc/network/interfaces`. I want to configure it using the GUI that `Ubuntu-18.04` provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) which will mean your interfaces are named something like `ens1` instead of `ethX`; those names should be consistent across reboots or regardless of adding any further network interfaces which usually causes the traditional `ethX` interfaces to change order.

Comment: Thanks.
Previously, the network interface names were ensX. I didn't know the reason of this naming convention. The reason i changed back to traditional naming convention was that i didn't know the reason (in order to reduce confusion, as a lot of online guides and references use ethX examples shown)